# Qt/Qml Application Window Title on Mac

Tags: qt, qml

When I create an application on Mac, I have two types of titles, namely

1. On the application title bar
2. On Mac main menu

The code below just changes the title on the application menu. But by default, on the Mac main menu, its the name of the project which is displayed. What am I missing? This is not an issue with Windows though.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

[image: App screenshot with app menu and main menu]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems, the only solution is to rename the `.pro` file and run the project again

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `Qt.application.name` to your application's name?

Usually done in main() before starting QML:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
...
app.setApplicationName("Your app name");
```

Comment: Hmm.. I did but doesn't seem to work. I believe this used to work on QtQuick version 1